# Не понимаю как работает такой массив

Tags: c#

```
if (Money >= ShopCost[index]){
   priceInClick += ShopBonus[index];
   money -= ShopCost[index];                    
   MessageBox.Show($"{ShopCost[index]}");
   ShopCost[index] *= 2;                 
}
```

Что я должен написать в `ShopCost[index]` и в `ShopBonus[index]`?
Как нужно обявить масивы ShopCost[index] и ShopBonus[index].
Ну я имею виду я обявляю масивы так

```
index = 2;
            ShopBonus = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

            ShopCost = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Но так не работает масив ShopCost не увеличеваеться на два.
Кто может подсказать

Comment: Если честно хотел сделать как на видио https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOd22Az66SY&t=1035s но там 3D unity  и в какойто момент становиться не понятно как он это сделал

Answer (score 2):

А в чем заключается вопрос?

Я пока могу только прокомментировать то, что делает выложенный код

```
// Если Money больше либо равно элементу, 
// стоящему на позиции index в массиве ShopCost, то
if (Money >= ShopCost[index]){          

// Прибавить к priceInClick значение этого элемента
   priceInClick += ShopBonus[index];        

// Из money вычесть значение того же элемента (который стоит на месте index в массиве ShopCost)
   money -= ShopCost[index];                  

// Показать сообщение пользователю со значением этого элемента массива  
   MessageBox.Show($"{ShopCost[index]}");   

// Увеличить значение этого элемента массива в два раза
   ShopCost[index] *= 2;                    
}
```

В языке C#, как и в других C-подобных языках, оператор `[ ]` является оператором обращения к элементу массива по заданному индексу (позиции от начала массива)

Comment: Это код для кликер точнее магазина кликера.Пермененые Money и money это одна и таже переменая.

Comment: @dima тогда ошибки (если они есть), скорее всего появились из-за того, что одна переменная называется `Money`, а другая `money`, что по существу две разные переменные.

Comment: Нет я поменял название переменой не помогла

Comment: @dima а что тогда не работает/работает не так, как хотелось? Можете описать?

Comment: Я просто хочю сделать так что бы после клика на кнопку повышалась цена в два раза

Comment: Поставьте вывод сообщения на последнее место, после увеличения цены в два раза.